# How to swap column values in pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a csv file where I have my datas like
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMVBv.jpg
Here in my case column vales were disordered. RollNo is exist under marks and vice versa. Name's were under Country column and vice versa.
How can I swap the values in between the columns and fix it in proper order.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like only _some_ of your rows have values in the wrong columns. There is no quick way to fix this (since mixed up columns are of the same dtype and could plausibly contain eachothers' values).

Comment: That's right.  Seems like the first 3 rows and last 2 rows are mis-aligned.  First 3 rows have correct column names but last 2 rows are not.

Comment: Actully this is an example. In my original file I have more than 5000 rows. Around 2000 rows are in proper order. Rest of the column values are in wrong place.

Comment: So probably you have to split the data into 2 dataframes.  Rename only the part in wrong columns and concat / append the 2 dataframes back together.

Comment: @SeaBean Thank you I fiexd it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the replace() function

```py
df['column name'] = df['column name'].replace(['old value'],'new value')
```

Find the official docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to rename your columns?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4], 'b': [3,4,5,6]})
df.rename(columns={'a': 'new_name'}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need an ad-hoc solution for one-time fix, you can do it quickly in one statement by:

```
df.columns = ['Total_marks', 'Country', 'Name', 'RollNo']
```

assuming `df` is the name of your dataframe.